# how to use automatic font size in jquery,html

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing sample program to re size a font size dynamically, I need a jquery with a sample program to learn,So that program could ve a text but that text related to the browser's size,when I minimize my window , The text size should be related to that browser size. I tried this one and  It is not helped. Here I included that one .

**Edit: Add code include in comment**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/…; (function($) { $.fn.resizeme = function(options) { var preferredHeight = 768; var displayHeight = $(window).height(); var percentage = displayHeight / preferredHeight; var newFontSize = Math.floor(fontsize * percentage) - 1; $("body").css("font-size", newFontSize); return this; } })(jQuery); </script> <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("p").resizeme(function(){ }); }); </script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>If you resize my window on me, I will resize.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
(function($) {
    $.fn.resizeme = function(options) {
         var preferredHeight = 768;  
  var displayHeight = $(window).height();
  var percentage = displayHeight / preferredHeight;
  var newFontSize = Math.floor(fontsize * percentage) - 1;
   $("body").css("font-size", newFontSize);
  return this;
}
})(jQuery);
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").resizeme(function(){
 
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you resize my window on me, I will resize.</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It s my program what I tried.

Comment: And why did you write it in the comments, instead of editing the question?

Comment: I tried,It shows some error tht s why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the way you have included jquery is wrong.
Secondly, You really dont need to include jquery for that.

you can use media queries for your requirement as shown in the fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/3dpLN/

also you are trying to use jquery library and javascript at the same time.
If you qant to use jquery , use the `.resize()` function
also if you really want to make the text dynamically responsive you want to do something like this : 
http://jsfiddle.net/qcmhq/

here the text size dynamically changes. you can surely play around with the numbers to get the desired result.

Comment: oh.thank u.I got it...then how to make the same thing with JQUERY.

Comment: oh.thank u.I got it...then how to make the same thing with JQUERY. But It response only for two sizes, How I can make it for every screen width.I don't want to write all width sizes in my program.